# Django string manipulation

Tags: django

If I received through a post method the following string

```
'Soccer,Tennis,BaseBall'
```

How can I, using django, separate the fields into an array in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use Django, you'd use Python.

```
>>> 'Soccer,Tennis,BaseBall'.split(',')
['Soccer', 'Tennis', 'BaseBall']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Soccer,Tennis,BaseBall'.split(',')
```